# Django middleware setting cache taking 10 seconds

Tags: python, django, memcached

I have discovered that this piece of code is taking up to 10s when under some load, and I don't get why.

Using django 1.8 with python 2.7

```py
from django.core.cache import cache
from datetime import datetime

class ActiveUserMiddleware:

def process_request(self, request):
    current_user = request.user
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        now = datetime.now()
        if current_user.in_class:
            cache.set('seen_%s_%s' % (str(current_user.in_class.id), current_user.username.replace(" ", "_")), now, settings.USER_LASTSEEN_TIMEOUT)
```

Using memcached

```
django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache
```

With settings

```
USER_LASTSEEN_TIMEOUT = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
```

And I know that the database calls and memcache calls are just taking millisecs, it hangs here somewhere in django.

Comment: What is `in_class`?

Comment: it's a foreign field to the school class the user is in.